# Converting File Geodatabase feature classes to shapefiles in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, convert, file-geodatabase

How can I convert a File Geodatabase feature class into a shapefile?

I found the help for ArcGIS Desktop 10.1 and it tells me:

> 2. On the main menu, click Customize > Toolbars > Production Mapping

but when I follow this menu, Production Mapping does not exist.

Comment: If I got your question right, in ArcMap, within Catalog window browse the gdb and then right click to Export to SHPs.

Comment: I prefer to use [Feature Class to Feature Class](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001200000021000000), as you can use it to go back b/n both formats.

Answer (score 16):

I recommend that you try the [Feature Class To Shapefile ( Conversion) tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/0012/00120000003m000000.htm) instead:

> Copies the features from one or more feature classes or layers to a
>   folder of shapefiles.

This should enable you to convert feature classes within your file geodatabase to shapefiles.

Answer (score 4):

One other quick and easy way if you have the layer open in ArcMap is to right click, select Data, then Export Data.  The default format there is shapefile.

Answer (score 3):

Open ArcCatalog, then select your gdb, right click, export, to Shapefile (Multiple), then just select Output folder and your done

[image: GDB export to shapefile]
[image: Feature Class to Shapefile]

Answer (score 2):

The tool that [PolyGeo has linked to](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/79427/115) will definitely do what you want.

Just so you know the Production Mapping toolbar would show up if you had the Production Mapping Extension, so that's why it wasn't in your list of toolbars.