# Opening.gbdindexes, gbdtable, atx, and freelist files in ArcMap or ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-online, file-geodatabase

I was sent these files in a zip folder, but I am not sure how to open them in ArcMap or ArcGIS Online.

Do I need to create a database or is it already there?

[[image: gbd1]

Comment: This is a data handling issue. Those files cannot be accessed outside a directory with a suffix of `.gdb`. Either the data was corrupted when created or when extracted. If the zipfile has a folder within it, you should extract it with "Extract... here" not by drilling into the file geodatabase folder and copying the files out. If the zipfile only contains those files, then the data was likely corrupted before you got it, and should be re-zipped and retransmitted. If there aren't more than the minimum of 40 files, either way, the data is corrupt, since 40 files constitutes an "empty" dataset.

Comment: This appears to be a near duplicate... [ArcMap doesn't recognize geodatabase files under "Add Data"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183789/arcmap-doesnt-recognize-geodatabase-files-under-add-data)